# Configurar Rota pagina MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, route

Tenho uma site e que ao entrar na pagina inicial ele é redirecionado para outra `view`.

Assim:

> www.exemplo.com redireciona para www.exemplo.com/Home/Hotsite

Isso porque eu tenho uma funcionalidade que ao entrar na `view` `Home/Index www.exemplo.com/xpto`, irá carregar a `view Index` que é a tela de login,  personalizada de acordo com o parâmetro passado(xpto) .

Gostaria de saber se é possível esconder a URL redirecionada da `view` Hotsite,  assim quando eu entrar `www.exemplo.com`, exibirá apenas `www.exemplo.com`, e não `www.exemplo.com/Home/Hotsite`.

É possível fazer isso sem alterar as `views`?

essas são as rotas que tenho:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Inicial",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Asp.Net MVC você está utilizando?

Comment: Tem, mas, preciso ver o seu arquivo de rotas e também se existe alguma rota configurado para base do site, poderia postar?

Comment: A versão é a asp.net  4

Comment: Eu coloque as rotas que eu tenho configuradas

Answer (score 0):

## **Resolvendo com áreas**

Você pode utilizar a funcionalidade de criar **áreas** *clique com o botão direito no nome do projeto e selecione Add / Area *

Com isso você consegue criar por exemplo rotas de admin:

1. site.com/admin/home
2. site.com/admin/users
3. site.com/admin/test

[Referência MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn877998.aspx)